# Qt Quick2 Custom Controls that Organize Their Children

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I would like to implement a custom Qt5 Quick 2 QML custom control that groups a set of arbitrary and varied buttons into a row with no spacing, gives it a margin, and then draws a little border around them (later, perhaps a shadow or other effect).

[image]

I am hoping to make the usage very simple rather than requiring lots of support structure but I do not now how to properly define a control than contains other controls and organizes them.

I could create a custom rectangle and then anchor a `RowLayout` to its interior,

```
BubbleButtonBar
{
    RowLayout
    {
       Button
       {
           text:"First"
       }
       Button
       {
           text:"Second"
       }
       Button
       {
           text:"Third"
       }
    }
}
```

but I was hoping to make it more automatic and look like this:

```
ButtonBar
{
   Button
   {
       text:"First"
   }
   Button
   {
       text:"Second"
   }
   Button
   {
       text:"Third"
   }
}
```

however, I don't know how to get the `ButtonBar.qml` file to insert its child controls into a given position:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Item {
    
    property int pad: 50
    property int borderSize: 2
    width:mainRow.width + pad
    height: mainRow.height + pad

    Rectangle
    {
        x: pad/2 - borderSize
        y: pad/2 - borderSize
        width:mainRow.width + borderSize*2
        height: mainRow.height + borderSize*2

        border.width: borderSize
        border.color: "red"

        RowLayout
        {
            id: mainRow
            spacing: 0
            x: borderSize
            y: borderSize
            // <------- How to get child controls to insert here?           
        }
    }
}
```

It appears that perhaps a custom [container control](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.7/qml-qtquick-controls2-container.html) might allow me to define a `contentItem` but it is unclear how this is done. Or if that is the most appropriate way ensure child controls find their way into the layout of a parent custom control.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use a `default property`.

```
// ButtonBar.qml
Item {
    default property alias contents: mainRow.data

    RowLayout {
        id: mainRow
    }
}
```

Then any children of the ButtonBar will get inserted into `mainRow`.